# Why does Mozilla's SSL Config Generator not disallow aNULL and MD5?

Tags: cryptography, openssl

I've been using for some time this ciphers suite from [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/tls-ssl-cipher-hardening/), to which I also added `!DSS`.

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

Recently I discovered [Mozilla's SSL Config Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), which generates a more detailed (and up-to-date) ciphers suite. However, I noticed that it isn't disallowing neither `aNULL` nor `MD5`.

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
```

What would be the likely reason for not doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list generated does not contain any ciphers or cipher sets which contain anonymous authentication or ciphers using MD5, so it is not necessary to explicitly disallow these. Actually the !DSS at the end is not needed too since none of the previously allowed ciphers contain anything which is covered by DSS.

For more information how the ciphers string is constructed and how to interpret  it see [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html).

Comment: !DSS disallows DSS certificates actually, isn't actually related to the cipher suites that can be negociated.

Comment: @BrunoRohée: from the documentation: "aDSS, DSS -  cipher suites using DSS authentication, i.e. the certificates carry DSS keys". But all the preceding ciphers in the list have authentication RSA or ECDSA and not DSS, so the !DSS does not forbid anything which was previously allowed.

Comment: Yup actually you're right

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the Acunetix one, the Mozilla generated configuration is a exhaustive whitelist, which doesn't contain any cipher suite using MD5. What would be the point of removing something that isn't here?